# using svg in LaTex (not Overleaf)

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, overleaf, svg

I used Overleaf for long times and I was able to use the `svgpackage` for my pictures in this way:

```
\includesvg[width=65mm]{pics/example.svg}
```

I moved for the first time to offline Latex with MikTex and Texstudio and I would like to still use svg pictures but it is not working.
I tried some suggestions found on the web but I'm still not able to do it. Moreover, I would like to have a solution which will work both with MikTex than with Overleaf.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have inkscape installed and is it in your path. Do you compile your document with shell-escape enabled (or however this option is called in miktex)?

Comment: yes, I followed the instruction found in another topic but it is still got an error: inkscape version not detected

Comment: Please post the exact error message that you get, and everything else from the log file that you think might be related. Another question: are you able to start Inkscape itself from the start menu in Windows?

Comment: yes, I'm able to start Inkscape from the start menu in Windows. The error message is: Package svg Error: Inkscape version not detected. \includesvg{temp.svg}

Comment: I solved the issue. The inkscape path was not correct, the bin folder was missing. The right one is: C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin